# 10TB HDD has a 9999GB partition but only allows me to access 215gb

Tags: hard-drive, partition, parted, ubuntu-20.04

[parted print all result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSPh6.jpg)

I have a 10tb hdd with 3 partitions and one flag (not sure what that means).
The flag is set as 215gb and that's all i'm able to access in the filesystem.
I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 and i would really like to access the rest of this iron wolf HDD.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
(The best fix would be one that wouldn't make me format the drive and loose my data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have LVM. A partition manager is limited in what it will show about logical volumes.

See what LVM looks like with a quick `pvs;` `vgs;` `lvs;`.  Probably whomever set this up did a smart thing and did not fully allocate space to volumes.

If PVs are not the full size of the partition/disk, fix that with `pvresize`.

Create new LVs with something like  `lvcreate --name lv --size 100g ubuntu-vg`   Create file system on that, and mount it where desired.

---

A hundreds of MB fat32 partition with the esp flag is an **E**FI **s**ystem **p**artition. A similarly small partition formatted ext4 on an otherwise LVM system is probably `/boot`.